# Defining an array of specific slider values in matplotlib vice using valmin and valmax

Tags: python, matplotlib, slider, interactive

Looking at the `slider_demo.py`, the author has the following code:

```
axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
axfreq = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor=axcolor)
axamp = plt.axes([0.25, 0.15, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor=axcolor)

sfreq = Slider(axfreq, 'Freq', 0.1, 30.0, valinit=f0, valstep=delta_f)
samp = Slider(axamp, 'Amp', 0.1, 10.0, valinit=a0)
```

where, in `sfreq`, for example, the values `0.1` and `30.0` are `valmin` and `valmax`, respectively, and the slider values are incremented by `delta_f`.

I would like to, instead, define an array of values

```
valarray = [0.1, 1, 3, 5, 15, 20, 27, 30]
```

where this array of values are the only values selected, displayed, or available as one moves the slider. This does not appear to be an explicit option for this widget.

It would also be helpful, but not necessary, that I am able to update this list dynamically.

Thanks in advance for your help and assistance.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the major ticks of the Slider with this line:

```
axfreq.set_xticks(np.array([0.1, 1, 3, 5, 15, 20, 27, 30]), minor = False)
```

eventually, you can also set minor ticks by setting `minor = True`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I was not aware of this feature, but I plan to use it! However, while this shows the tick marks, the slider does not stop at each of these user defined discrete ticks, which is what I am seeking. –

Comment: In that case, maybe you should consider to use a discrete range selection widget as a `RadioButtons`. `Slider` is thought to be used for a continuous range selection.

Comment: I thought about that, but unfortunately, there are too many numbers and the plot would become cluttered.

Comment: [This does not work anymore automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71186196/8881141) with matplotlib 3.5.1.